# Twitter api to post statuses not working due to authentication error

Tags: node.js, authentication, twitter

I am creating an application that posts tweets containing information from a db.

I am using the twitter api client package from NPM and my code is below:

```
var Twitter = require("twitter");
var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key : process.env.TWITTER_CUSTOMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret : process.env.TWITTER_SECRET_KEY,
  access_token_key : process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  access_token_secret : process.env.TWITTER_SECRET_TOKEN
});

function createProjectTweet(projectName, url)
{
    client.post("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=" + projectName + " " + url +
    " has just been added!", function(err, tweets, response)
    {
        console.log("tweet posted: " + response);
    });
}
```

My keys are fine and I have ensured they were correct but I keep getting the following error:

```
[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: *Bad Authentication data.* > Check if all keys are correct. (.. and readable from your `process.env.` file)

Comment: Not the case here as the keys are matching perfectly